# Is there a newer version of IQ Driver which can work with MySQL Community Server 5.5?

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I am using LinqPad 4.31 and I'm failed to get it worked with MYSQL 5.5. I always get this error : **Connection Error: Bad handshake**

Is there a newer version of IQ Driver or a workaround ?

Comment: Work in progress... stay tuned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQPad's IQ driver has just been updated with the latest DevArt drivers for MySQL and Oracle. Try downloading the IQ again and let us know.